# acabo de subir una actualizacion de una app y al abrirla dice "se ha detenido" ¿por que pasa esto?

Tags: c#, unity

He creado una aplicación, que se llama "Jumping Willy", y la he subido a Google Play pero al subir una actualización, en la que se incluía anuncios, al ejecutarla no se abre y dice "Jumping Willy se ha detenido". ¿Alguien podría ayudarme, puesto que no entiendo que ha podido pasar? Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Bienvenido Guillermo.. Para saber como funciona el sitio te recomiendo hagas un [tour]... Y para evitar que tu publicación tenga puntuaciones negativas o reportes te recomiendo que vayas a [ask] y luego edites la pregunta según corresponda, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y no nos das suficiente información para ayudarte...

Comment: si desinstala la version previa y vuelves a instalar de cero agreagando la version mas actual desde el store, ejecuta?